# Improving boolean circuits w.r.t. a probability distribution

Tags: reference-request, circuit-complexity, boolean-functions, circuits

This is a reference request. Consider the following problem on boolean circuits [ 1 ]:

- **Given:** Boolean circuit $B$ and probability distribution $\mathbb{P}$ on inputs to $B$.
- **Task:** Find one or more equivalent Boolean circuits $B'$ that 'perform better'
  than $B$ if the inputs are as given by $\mathbb{P}$.

What has been
done that looks like it is related, even loosely?  Naturally, there
are numerous ways we can understand things like "perform better", e.g. fewer gates, fewer gates of a specific type, less depth. Minimally, the new circuit(s) should
produce the same output (with the edge case that if the probability
of an input is 0 then $B$ and $B'$ don't have to agree on that input).

Here is an analogy that feels similar: Huffman coding [ 2 ],
which gives an optimal coding for any specific probability of
character occurrence. Similarly, it would appear to be possible to
specialise a boolean circuit to a probability distribution on inputs.

Boolean circuits and their complexities have been
formalised in many ways, and I'm not particularly attached by any
specific definition: my exact use case is unlikely to have been
considered already. At the same time, all existing approaches
are probably full of interesting ideas that might be adaptable to my
use case.

---

1. Wikipedia: [Boolean circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_circuit)
2. Wikipedia: [Huffman coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding)